How to find the following HTML Element
I have a menu with submenu with a structure like this:
<ul>
  <li>
    <a class="navigation-item">Menu Item 1</a>
    <a class="submenu-toggle"><a/>
    <ul class="submenu">
      <li>
        <a class="navigation-item">Submenu Item 1</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>

I want to add a class to submenu-toggle if Submenu Item 1 is selected. How can I find the submenu-toggle in this case?
closest('li') won' work, this will only find the li after the submenu. closest('li > .submenu-toggle') doesn't work either because the .submenu-toggle has to be an ancestor of the submenu item. If I could select the correct li, I could then use find('.submenu-toggle'). But how do I select the correct li?

just realised I could just do closest('li').closest('li').finde('.submenu-toggle') provided the structure is always the same. Is there a better way?

What do you have your click(?) handler on - the .navigation-item element, or the parent LI?

@C3roe on the submenu item 1 with .navigation-item class

Are they not collapsed? How would I click on the "Submenu Item 1" if it is not visible? Can you make a [mcve]?

Also a is not a self closing tag

A real generic one with no jQuery needed, just the closest and the querySelector methods together with css-selectors ... yourInnerElementReference.closest('li:has(.submenu-toggle)').querySelector('.submenu-toggle'). Have a look at the functional :has() CSS pseudo-class _

Why not $(this).closest("a.submenu-toggle"); ?

@Twisty because it is not an ancestor of submenu item 1

@yangsunny that's not how it looks in your example. You have an un-closed a element that would be the parent to your ul.

Regardless of the already above commented approach of mine ...

A real generic one with no jQuery needed, just the closest and the querySelector methods together with css-selectors ... yourInnerElementReference.closest('li:has(.submenu-toggle)').querySelector('.submenu-toggle'). Have a look at the functional :has() CSS pseudo-class

... there is a big chance that the OP does not need any JavaScript based solution at all in order to style the toggle-element. This of cause does not imply that JS is entirely obsolete in order to achieve all of the required menu-behaviors, but I would give even that one a real good try.


.menu {
  display: inline-block;
  
  li {
    margin: 4px 0;
  }
  > li {
    position: relative;
    margin: 12px 0;

    > .toggle {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      right: 0;
    }
  }
}
.submenu:has(a:active, a:focus, a:target) {
  + .toggle {
    color: green;
  }
}
<ul class="menu">
  <li>
    <a href="#">Menu Item 1</a>

    <ul class="submenu">
      <li>
        <a href="#">Submenu Item 1.1</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Submenu Item 1.2</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <div tabindex="0" class="toggle">toggle</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Menu Item 2</a>

    <ul class="submenu">
      <li>
        <a href="#">Submenu Item 2.1</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Submenu Item 2.2</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <div tabindex="0" class="toggle">toggle</div>
  </li>
</ul>



And whereas the above example-code shows an HTML/CSS-only approach which achieves what the OP did ask for, the next provided example code can be a solution for what the OP actually might really need in terms of ...

the behavior which one would expect from a nested menu where the submenu structure can be toggled in between its expanded and collapsed state,

a semantically correct HTML structure and its related CSS rules

as well as a minimal JS footprint.




function handleNavigationClick(evt) {
  const toggleElement = evt.target.closest('.expand-toggle');

  if (toggleElement) {
    toggleElement.classList.toggle('indicate-expanded');
  }
}
document
  .querySelector('nav')
  .addEventListener('click', handleNavigationClick);
li {
  margin: 4px 0;
}
menu {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

menu:not(.submenu) {
  display: inline-block;
  
  > li {
    position: relative;
    margin: 12px 0;
  }
}
.submenu {
  display: none;
}

[type="button"].expand-toggle {

  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  width: 1em;
  border: none;
  background: none;
  text-indent: 1em;
  text-wrap: nowrap;

  &:after {
    z-index: -1;
    position: absolute;
    left: -.77em;
    top: .07em;
    content: ">";
  }
  &.indicate-expanded {
    &:after {
      top: .04em;
      content: "v";
    }

    ~ .submenu {
      display: block;
      margin-left: 2em;
    }
  }
}
<nav>
  <menu>
    <li>
      <button type="button" class="expand-toggle" title="toggle submenu display">
        toggle submenu display
      </button>

      <a href="#">Menu Item 1</a>

      <menu class="submenu">
        <li>
          <a href="#">Submenu Item 1.1</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Submenu Item 1.2</a>
        </li>
      </menu>
    </li>
    <li>
      <button type="button" class="expand-toggle" title="toggle submenu display">
        toggle submenu display
      </button>

      <a href="#">Menu Item 2</a>

      <menu class="submenu">
        <li>
          <a href="#">Submenu Item 2.1</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Submenu Item 2.2</a>
        </li>
      </menu>
    </li>
  </menu>
</nav>




It is way better to find the root of the context, i.e., the container and do the actions relative to that. In the snippet below I loop the li children of #myul as the roots of the contexts, create a click handler on the .navigation-item which will toggle the active class of submenu-toggle.


$(function() {
    $("#myul > li").each(function() {
        let that = $(this);
        that.find("a.navigation-item").click(function() {
            that.find("a.submenu-toggle").toggleClass("active");
        });
    });
});
.submenu-toggle.active {
    color: green;
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="myul">
  <li>
    <a class="navigation-item">Menu Item 1</a>
    <a class="submenu-toggle">some text</a>
    <ul class="submenu">
      <li>
        <a class="navigation-item">Submenu Item 1</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class="navigation-item">Menu Item 2</a>
    <a class="submenu-toggle">some text</a>
    <ul class="submenu">
      <li>
        <a class="navigation-item">Submenu Item 2</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>




To achieve this, you can traverse the DOM to find the correct li element that contains both the submenu-toggle
and the selected submenu item.
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Assuming 'Submenu Item 1' is selected
  $('.submenu .navigation-item').on('click', function() {
    // Find the closest 'li' ancestor that contains the submenu
    var parentLi = $(this).closest('ul.submenu').parent('li');
    
    // Find the 'submenu-toggle' within that 'li'
    var submenuToggle = parentLi.find('.submenu-toggle');
    
    // Add the desired class to the 'submenu-toggle'
    submenuToggle.addClass('active');
  });
});


Please note that answers created by AI are banned at SO.

You need to traverse the DOM structure from the selected submenu item up to the parent <li> thaat contains both the submenu and the toggle button. Then, you can find the .submenu-toggle within that parent <li>.
// Assuming the selected submenu item has a class 'selected'

$('.submenu .navigation-item.selected').parents('li').first().find('> .submenu-toggle').addClass('active');


I don't know how it translates to jquery, but in plain Javascript you can just do:
event.target.parentElement.querySelector(".submenu-toggle").classList.add("new-class")


If i were you I'll use data-menuItem1, data-menuItem2, data-menuItem3... etc. attribute to find correct li.
In other words you should update your HTML markup.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
